# How to add two new extra tabs on product in admin back office

Tags: php, prestashop

In prestashop Using this hook  "hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra" we can make new tab in admin back office when editing a new product , I want to add two tabs so what can I do ?

Comment: Maybe show a [mcve] for context?

Answer (score 0):

You created a module that will be hooked on the hook "hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra"

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create two separated modules as tabs are instances of Modules hooked into proper place, for example tab name is just a module name...